# Can't activate free trial on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform

I also tried the Google Support, but a billing account ID is required to send the support form, and a billing account it is precisely what I am unable to create.

At the Google Cloud Platform, I click on the button "Try for Free" in top right corner and got stuck in the next screen "Try Cloud Platform for free" (this will occurs if I choose to create my first billing account). I do check "Yes" for both questions, click on the button above "AGREE AND CONTINUE", it turns into a spinning circle and stays forever like this. There is some JavaScript errors in the console: invalid source ''report-sample'' and ''strict-dynamic'', and finally failed to load resource, address family incompatible with protocols family. Tried on Safari and Chrome and also on FireFox in Windows 7 (VMWare Fusion).

I need this to keep my Google Maps working. Please Help!

Comment: Contact Google Support.

Comment: Per @geocodezip, try: https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/free_trial_support

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip and @ DazWilkin, I could finally ask for Google Support help! Let's see the answer... I have found more people in my situation and I was thinking about to post the solution here, but got a -1 on my question, do you think is not relevant to the community?

Comment: @geocodezip: Google answered to me that I have no free support. But I can't buy anything so I have no support at all. One suggestion mentioned in the email is join the community, that is to ask stack-overflow as described on the overview page, so we have a looping issue of support here! There is also a vote for closing my question... that's disappointing, though I will have to call somebody...

Comment: Sounds like a canned response.  Your question is off-topic for StackOverflow, we are not Google support.  Creating a Google Billing account **requires** Google's support. See [Why we're not customer support for (your favorite company)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: @geocodezip The email Google sent to me estates "You can also find answers to your questions from our communities (...)". Than has a link to a page that indicates Stackoverflow as source of support. I did believe there was some kind of relation or partnership between this community and Google. Sorry if I misunderstood, will bother you no more. Maybe the answer should be we are not customer support for Google Cloud Platform, or something, your call.

Comment: Developer console is used for both Google Cloud Platform and Google Maps Platform. The  "Try for Free" option is only available for Google Cloud Platform. In case of Google Maps Platform you have to enable billing as specified in the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account

Comment: @xomena In order to use Google Maps Platform, you have to define a billing account in Google Cloud Platform, since July 16. After, you have to link the Maps to the account, so you will use the free trial. Without this action, won't be possible to increase Map Loadings for JavaScript dynamic loading (my case) more than 1.

Answer (score 0):

The "Try Cloud Platform for free" page has finally worked today. Was a bug after all and they manage to correct it.

If you are reading this because your page is still freezing, try to clear all caches and local content of your browsers. If still won't work, I advise you to call Google support by phone.